# Replacing None with NULL or blank for VARCHAR and 0 or blank for INT fields from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3

I am trying to fetch data from a database, put them in a dataframe and load them to AWS S3.

For the fields that contains None values, the values get loaded to S3 as None. I would like to have None in VARCHAR fields to be NULL or Blank and None in INT fields to be 0 or blank.

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(conn)
sql = 'SELECT id, name from table_a'
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)
df=df.applymap(str) 
csv_buffer = BytesIO()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
with gzip.GzipFile(mode='w', fileobj=csv_buffer) as zipped_file:
        df.to_csv(TextIOWrapper(zipped_file, 'utf8'), index=False)
s3.Object(bucket[env],dest_filename).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

The output that i am getting while print(df) is -

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | None |
| None | John |

I would want the dataframe to be loaded to S3 as below -

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
|  | John |

How can i handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply change the value of None to an empty value in python, you can try:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(str())
```

int() can be substituted for str() as well, or empty quotes: ''

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried this ```df.replace([None], np.nan, inplace=True)
 df.fillna('', inplace=True)``` and it worked too.

Comment: nice! glad I could help